# Apparmor has hats like null-12b08

Tags: apache2, 12.04, apparmor

I am running a Ubuntu 12.04.2 server with Apache using mod_apparmor. When I run `aa-status`, I see thousands and thousands (seriously, over 100,000) of profiles with names like

```
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2//DEFAULT_URI//null-12b08
```

Some of them even stack:

```
/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2//scoop//null-2dd76//null-2dd77
```

What are these? Are they actually hats? If so, why are there so many of them, and is that a potential problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These hats are the result of a profile in complain mode. They will accumulate, but you can clear them with a restart. Once the profile is in enforce mode, they will stop being created.

Comment: Is it possible to do this w/o a restart though, as a restart would make all the already running processes unconfined?